# Why isn't my Screen On/Off BroadcastReceiver working?

Tags: java, android, android-broadcastreceiver

Here is my Receiver file. Which I feel doesn't have any kind of problem. I just prints the type of intent which is passed. According to me onReceive is never called. I guess there is a problem with my manifest itself? Or any other ideas? The Receiver is not linked to any anyother code in the application.

```
package sharukh.locky;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class BroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public BroadCastReceiver()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.i("rece", intent.getAction());
    }
}
```

My Manifest also looks good, but I can't figure out why it isn't working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="sharukh.locky"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAGufoN9huWkmw8nTskk2aaFHW1gXn1Z7Q"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <!-- Activities -->
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Tutorial"/>
        <activity android:name=".TutorialSelectApp"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".LockScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_lock_screen"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>

        <!-- Services -->
        <service
            android:name=".LockyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"/>

        <receiver
            android:name=".BroadCastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I haven't dynamically added/registered/unregistered any receivers. I would require some help here.

Comment: Both of the actions you've registered your Receiver for are broadcast with `FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY`, which means that they can only be received by dynamically registered Receivers. Your statically registered Receiver class won't get them.

Comment: your package name is "sharukh.locky" right? is your broadcast reciver in the same package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by trying dynamic calling of broadcast like below

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    //Create broadcast object
    BroadcastReceiver mBroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {    
    //When Event is published, onReceive method is called
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("[BroadcastReceiver]", "MyReceiver");

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            Log.d("[BroadcastReceiver]", "Screen ON");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            Log.d("[BroadcastReceiver]", "Screen OFF");
        }

    }
};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        registerReceiver(mBroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
        registerReceiver(mBroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));
    }
}
```

Comment: Works flawlessly, I never knew the concept of `FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY`. Thanks.

Comment: It should be noted that it is actually stated in [the documentation for ACTION_SCREEN_OFF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) that it cannot be received by receivers declared in the manifest.

Comment: But this only works if and when the APP is running, Isn't it ?